# "No Mesh Data To Join" Error

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm working on a door. I created the handle in a different Blender project and linked it to my main project. I created a door in the main project and have been trying to Join (Ctrl-J) with the handle. I get the "No Mesh Data To Join" error, but I don't understand why, considering I did create it out of mesh in a separate file. I even linked the door into the handle's file and tried to join things that way, it still didn't work. What could be the problem?[image: Door]
[image: Handle]